# Browser for AIX 6.1

Tags: aix

Does anyone have a suggestion for a "current browser" for AIX?

IBM's recommendation is Mozilla Firefox for AIX - Version  3.6.25.2 
2011 era.

Can't find anything much more recent. 
There's [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/), but even that is barely a 2012 release

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is going to be to follow IBM's suggestion for cases where you are using the browser to interact with other IBM equipment such as HMCs and V7000 arrays. What will probably happen when you call in for support is that they will tell you to use the supported browser.

Comment: Is anybody taking care of applying security updates to that browser? If it turns out the suggestion is to use a browser, which has not had any security updates for three years, chances are it is not good advice, regardless of who you got it from.

Comment: I agree completely, but my advice is based on the HMC or whatever possibly requiring a specific browser coupled with the idea that you are going to end up calling support at some point. The use case I'm speaking to is generally for connecting to IBM equipment on the local LAN.